# Python in Jupyter Notebook - Import CPI get an error message

Tags: python

When i try to import cpi in jupyter notebook, i get this error message. Does anyone have an idea how to address this issue?

---

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/59/k880nk6s3m3_fp0p5dc6hfhc0000gn/T/ipykernel_6186/1241436912.py in 
<module>
----> 1 import cpi

     ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cpi/__init__.py in <module>
     19 # Parse data for use
     20 logger.info("Parsing data files from the BLS")
---> 21 areas = parsers.ParseArea().parse()
     22 items = parsers.ParseItem().parse()
     23 periods = parsers.ParsePeriod().parse()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cpi/parsers.py in parse(self)
     58         logger.debug("Parsing area file")
     59         object_list = MappingList()
---> 60         for row in self.get_file("cu.area"):
     61             obj = Area(row["area_code"], row["area_name"])
     62             object_list.append(obj)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cpi/parsers.py in get_file(self, file)
     35 
     36         # Query this file
---> 37         query = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM "{file}"')
     38         columns = [d[0] for d in query.description]
     39         result_list = [dict(zip(columns, r)) for r in query.fetchall()]

OperationalError: no such table: cu.area
```

Answer (score -2):

As a developer, when I try to apply fetching CPI index via python, the library gives following error instead of a complete result sheet:

```
Error when importing CPI: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: cu.area #62
```

Under normal practice, the developer should update its dependency as updated as possible. IN reality, palewi api Version 1.0.5 works, but the newest verison 1.0.9 does not. It gives me this no such table error as seen below. It looks like it may be missing a DB file or some issues with the DB file its self:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cpi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cpi\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    areas = parsers.ParseArea().parse()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cpi\parsers.py", line 60, in parse
    for row in self.get_file("cu.area"):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cpi\parsers.py", line 37, in get_file
    query = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM "{file}"')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: cu.area
>>>
```

Please follow https://github.com/palewire/cpi/issues/62.

Docs: https://palewi.re/docs/cpi/

Updates:
Version 1.0.10 is fixed